# Scalable URL Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am organizing sub-websites into different folders on a LAMP server for ease of maintenance, but do not want the end user to know they are organized into those folders via the URL.

Directory structure example:

```
/category1/website1
/category1/website2
/category2/website3
/category2/website4
/category2/website5
/category3/website6
/category4/website7
etc.
```

Currently it shows as `http://www.example.com/category1/website1` however I want it to show as `http://www.example.com/website1` all the time - even if they put the category name in there.

The trick is I need to do this from a `.htaccess` file with X amount of categories having X amount of sub-websites in them. Currently I am using

```
Redirect 301 /website1 /category1/website1
```

for each website to allow users to use the shorter link, but ultimately they end up seeing the category in the address and the `.htaccess` file is long with 200+ sub-websites involved. :(

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you know in what category a website is ? If you redirect `/website1` to `/category1/website1`, how do you know `website1` is in `category1` ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: I manually create the directory for each website and they each have a unique name - so, for example, website1 would never be in multiple categories.  Internally they are named logically, kind of like "apple" would be in the "fruit" category not a "meat" category type of thing.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot redirect dynamically without knowing the category associated with the website. You will either have to store your category/website mapping somewhere or you will need to hardcode it.

Comment: OK, if you could show me how to do it manually for multiple websites then at least that is better than a "Redirect 301" which still shows the category name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `mod_rewrite` it's pretty straight-forward if you are going to manually enter them in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/website1$ /category1/website1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/website2$ /category1/website2 [L,NC]
```

It's possible to create a `RewriteMap` as well.  There's a lot of helpful information in the [documention](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Believe me, forum posting was my last resort after looking online and at documentation!  In trying out your example, it appears to just redirect as if it were a "Redirect 301", my intent was to hide the category folder name as well.  Most online examples show how to do that for a single website, but not multiple as far as I can tell.

Comment: Example: ------ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/category1/ ---------- 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category1/$1 [L]

Comment: Do you still have other `Redirects` in place?  The example shouldn't be redirecting.

Comment: @gcs If you were seeing a "redirect" then it was quite possibly a cached 301 redirect from your earlier attempts. You will need to have cleared your browser cache and removed your existing mod_alias `Redirect` directives.

Comment: As it stands, the above directives won't actually do anything in a `.htaccess` context, because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. (Neither will they rewrite anything other than `/website1`, and not `/website1/<something>`. Which again will fail to do anything because mod_dir will 301 redirect `/website1` to `/website1/` to append a trailing slash.)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no discernible "pattern" that links the website to the *category* subdirectory and you are limited to `.htaccess` then you have no choice but to manually list all the mappings in your `.htaccess` file, in the same way you have listed the redirects.

Assuming you want to *internally rewrite* a URL of the form `/website1/<something>` to `/category1/website1/<something>` - in the same way the `Redirect` directive works (which is prefix-matching).

You could do something like the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(website1/.*) /category1/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(website2/.*) /category1/$1 [L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. eg. If you request `/website1/foo` then it will rewrite to `/category1/website1/foo`.

This does require that you request at least `/website1/`, with a trailing slash (since this is a *directory* of sorts).

You can potentially group sites together that are in the same category. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^((website3|website4|website5)/.*) /category2/$1 [L]
```

> I want it to show as `http://www.example.com/website1` all the time - **even if they put the category name in there**

For this you would need to implement the reverse... a redirect to remove the *category* from the URL. However, an added complication is that you only want to redirect direct requests and not rewritten requests (as above).

This will need to go *before* the internal rewrites above.

Unless there is a discernible pattern that distinguishes category names then you will need a rule for each category. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^category1/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

...and repeat for each category.

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that we are only targeting direct requests and not rewritten requests.

Change 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - only once you have confirmed that it works OK in order to avoid caching issues.

However, this may be easier (and more "scalable") to implement with an additional `.htaccess` file in each of the category subdirectories instead. And this would be the same directives in each category subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Since the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is relative to the directory containing the `.htaccess` file, the `$1` backreference contains the URL-path less the `/category/` prefix.